# How to refresh API request in Loop

Tags: python, api, loops, yahoo-finance

I want to display the **current** foreign exchange rate every 10 seconds on an LED matrix. However the code below seems to only pull the exchange rate once and repeating it every 10 seconds. Only when I manually run the code again the exchange rate updates. How can I refresh the API pull request?

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import time
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('EURCHF=X')


while True:
    print yahoo_financials.get_current_price()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead calling API once in first line, you can call that in while loop after each 10 seconds sleep time.

```py
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import time

while True:
    yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('EURCHF=X')
    print yahoo_financials.get_current_price()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! Much appreciated